# How to include static library in another ndk project?

Tags: android

I have created static library of one of my project say libABC.a. Now i want to use this static library in another android project at jni layer. The second project would also have its own .cpp files inside jni folder, which would be using the functions of libABC.a static library. Now my question is what are the steps through which i can include static library into another project at jni layer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY` in your Android.mk file.

They have a very detailed explanation in `android-ndk/docs/PREBUILT.xml`

In short you add to your Android.mk something like

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := anynamehere
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yourlib.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

before your module