# Opening SD card BMP file from NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

Can any one help me with a code snippet to open an image file from SD card and assign it to a variable in NDK?
thanking you in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SD card is usually located at `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd` Use Android call `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` to find out the actual path and pass it to your C code via JNI.

Once you have the path in your C code just open the file like in plain C or C++:

```
FILE* File = fopen( FileName , "rb" );
fclose( File );
```

Comment: Please let me know how can I open it as bitmap?

Comment: You need to use 3rd party library to load a bitmap. Take a look at FreeImage: http://freeimage.sourceforge.net It runs smoothly on Android and supports many image formats.

Comment: How to reference the library from the NDK?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889229/how-to-include-static-library-in-another-ndk-project

Comment: Is there any way I can get a .so file of freeimage?

Comment: Not .so but .a. Download Linderdaum Engine SDK http://www.linderdaum.com - it contains precompiled FreeImage for Android.

Comment: Can I use that directly in android project like we use .so?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14181/discussion-between-sergey-k-and-sreekanth-karumanaghat)

Comment: No-no. It should be linked into your .so. I have posted a link above where you can find the details how to link static library into your Android .so

Comment: I have posted it in chat Room discussion between us.